# Use of flavour dimensions in build.gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy, build.gradle

We can build multiple variants of application using product flavours field in build gradle. Why flavour dimension? And it is made compulsory with error message, "All flavours should now belong to flavour dimension"

If it has sensible uses, How and where can we differentiate configuration for different flavour dimensions?

All other blogs and posts I referred didn't give me satisfying answers and most tell me "you won't need it". Please throw some light.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd best describe flavour dimensions as a way of grouping flavours.

The one use case I can think of is this.

- You have a free and paid flavour under a dimension of tier.
- You have a test and prod flavour which point to different backends under a dimension of environment.

When you assemble all you end up with a version for each tier and environment so you can test a free/test version, free/prod version etc.

You don't need to inspect the dimension, just put whatever variables/ conditional code against the flavour as has always been the case.

An example using multiple dimensions

```
,,,
flavorDimensions "tier", "env"

productFlavors {
    paid {
        dimension "tier"
        ... add variables here
    }

    free {
        dimension "tier"
        versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + " free"
        ... add variables here
    }

    test {
         dimension "env"
         ... add variables here
    }

    prod {
         dimension "env"
         ... add variables here
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Ya I understood that it is combination of preferences. one more question is "You don't need to inspect the dimension" means you don't have any configuration and no folder segregation required. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct, if your using folders to segregate code per flavour you don't need to add anything new for dimensions.

Comment: Can you please add a snippet for the example stated?

Comment: Snippet added to answer

Comment: Old post but for future people who needs more information you could just  check that article, https://medium.com/@mds6058/breaking-down-android-flavor-dimensions-4ea97fbac8a4

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases, you may want to combine configurations from multiple product flavors. [source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions)

Previously, you could not combine product flavors, e.g. `full` and `minApi27`. Flavor dimensions are groupings of product flavors, and you can combine flavors from different dimensions. Examples:

- `api` dimension: `minApi24` and `minApi27` flavors
- `mode` dimension: `demo`, `full` flavors
- CodeChimp's example: `tier`: `free`, `paid` flavors

> The number of build variants Gradle creates is equal to the product of the number of flavors in **each** flavor dimension and the number of build types you configure.
>
> Build variant: [minApi24, minApi23, minApi21][Demo, Full][Debug, Release]
> [source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions)

So even though we had 4 product flavors and 2 build types (`4 x 2`), we did not just get 8 build variants. We got **12**. Each flavor from a dimension (minApi24, minApi23, minApi21 each create a build variant with the build type and other flavor dimensions.

Read more at the [flavor dimensions documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions).